# Writing Events to Specific EventViewer

Tags: c#, event-viewer

I have read multiple articles and SO questions on the Windows Event Viewer. However, I am still unable to accomplish my goal. I have a Windows Service that I'll call "Social". I want to write information from this Windows Service to the Windows Event Viewer. At this time, I'm trying the following:

```
var message = "Test Log";
using (var sw = File.AppendText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test.txt"))
{
  sw.WriteLine(message);
}

var eventLog = new EventLog();
eventLog.Source = "Service";
eventLog.Log = "Social";

eventLog.BeginInit();
if (EventLog.SourceExists(eventLog.Source) == false)
{
  EventLog.CreateEventSource(eventLog.Source, "Social");
}
eventLog.EndInit();

eventLog.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

I added the "test.txt" file just to ensure my code was being reached. That code runs fine. However, I never see my message written in the Event Viewer. In fact, I never see a new Event source get created. I was expecting to go to the Windows Event Viewer and see a new item located at "Event Viewer -> Applications and Services Logs -> Social Media Analyzer". However, I do not see that anywere.

Notably, the "Social" log exists in the event viewer. However, nothing gets written to it. The logs get written to the "Application" log instead. It's almost like the Windows Service is ignoring the fact that I want to write to a specific log.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
eventLog.Log = "Application";
...
EventLog.CreateEventSource(eventLog.Source, "Application");
```

You're writing your events to the Application Log under "Windows Logs". The events should specify the Source (column) as being "Social Media Analyzer".

If you want to write to a custom log you need something like

```
EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyEventSource", "Social Media Analyzer");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm slightly confused by your response though. In your example, is the Source "Social Media Analyzer" or "MyEventSource"? In either case, it's still not working for me. Shouldn't it be `EventLog.CreateEventSource("Service", "Social Media Analyzer");`?